# Crm Dynamics web api 8.2 request filter grouping apparently broken

Tags: dynamics-crm-365

accordingly to MSDN documentation ([LINK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx)) it seems to be possible to apply grouping to our requests filter through parenthesis like that:

```
(contains(name,'sample') or contains(name,'test')) and revenue gt 5000
```

Unfortunately this seems to be completely broken and records are returned like i never put in there parenthesis at all.

Is this a WEB API bug or i'm missing something?

Thanks in advance.

This is my web API call:

```
https://<organization_link>/api/data/v8.2/cust_entity?$selec‌​t=cust_fullname,stat‌​ecode&$count=true&$f‌​ilter=(contains(cust‌​_fullname,%27testFir‌​stName%27)%20or%20co‌​ntains(cust_fullname‌​,%27testLastName%27)‌​)%20and%20statecode%‌​20eq%200
```

I've modified it a bit to preserve customer privacy.

Comment: It is not just parentheses but its the brackets that you are missing. But all in all more info is needed to help you

Comment: I edited my post adding the filter part of the web API call taken from Chrome browser inspector.
As you can see i put brackets around the "contains" OR expression, but the entire expression is evaluated from left to right like they're never there.

CRM returns 5000 records (retrieve max limit) instead of a few dozens, including of course the ones that don't contains "Test" or "Record" inside fullname field.

Comment: You are clearily doing something wrong with your request, I just checked that grouping for version 8.2 works just fine (with the same "contains" as you have. Maybe post your whole code and request, because right now it's hard to tell what have you done wrong. Looking at your call I would say that you encoded the request badly because you clearily have some encoding there (%20 for example) but not entirely (' are not encoded, they should be %27). So maybe you are doing some double encoding? Post the code you use to retrieve the values.

Comment: I copy/pasted an hybrid version of the encoded request that i edited in notepad.

I changed ' with %27 in my original post (it's what i'm truly getting). Encoding is just fine.

Comment: I'm missing the full sample of request you're making - maybe recording fiddler trace and attaching it would help.

Comment: Here is an example of call we tried without success.


`https://<organization_link>/api/data/v8.2/cust_entity?$select=cust_fullname,statecode&$count=true&$filter=(contains(cust_fullname,%27testFirstName%27)%20or%20contains(cust_fullname,%27testLastName%27))%20and%20statecode%20eq%200`.


I've modified it a bit to preserve customer privacy.